# Firebase how to allow "Range" Header

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I set my CORS header for Firebase Storage with the following `cors.json` and `gsutil`

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET", "OPTIONS"],
    "responseHeader": ["Range", "Content-Type"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

But I still get this error:

> MLHttpRequest cannot load http://url_to.csv. Request header field
>   Range is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight
>   response.

I also tried replacing `Range` with `Content-Range` but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: Where you ever able to get Range requests to work in Firebase Storage?
If so can you show me your cors.json file?
Im using Shaka player loading a mpd dash manifest, and cant get the firebase storage to allow the range request

Comment: I have the same issue as well, if anyone has figured it out please post the info here!